# Jekyll Bootstrap with Rouge Highlighting not working on Windows

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap, rouge

I have just begun working with Jekyll and it seems like a really neat tool, however I cannot make highlighting to work. I would like to use 'rouge' highlighter for that purpose to use the same tool that will be later used by github pages - but when my pages are being served, they contain only raw code block.
I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

This are the steps that I am following:

1. I am following Jekyll Bootstrap Quick Start instructions to the letter [Link](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/usage/jekyll-quick-start.html)
2. Running command **jekyll serve** works as expected, default website is served. No errors in command line.
3. I am installing rouge via **gem install rouge**
4. I have verified that rouge is installed by checking **gem list**
5. I am adding **highlighter: rouge** to *_config.yml* file (replacing the default pygments)
6. I have added to following section to markdown page:

   ````
   ``` csharp
   public interface ITest : ITestKey
   {
       Task<string> SayHello(string name);
   }
   ```
   ````
7. I have created css style file by running **rougify style monokai > test.css** command
8. I have added that style to served page

   ```
   <link href="{{ ASSET_PATH }}/css/test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
   ```

Now I would expect that the served page would contain code block with appropriate spans. That is not the case  though - no errors or warning are thrown but the outcome of transformation is as follows:

```
  <div class="highlighter-rouge">
      <pre class="highlight">
          <code>
              public interface ITest : ITestKey
              {
                  Task&lt;string&gt; SayHello(string name);
              }
          </code>
      </pre>
    </div>
```

Could anyone please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right.
Turns out I was doing everything well...
However I was also using [MetroUI Styling](http://metroui.org.ua/) with default metro.js file included to website. 
Turns out that default metroui script was breaking the formatting...

Answer (score 1):

First things first then.

**1st**. Run Jekyll trough [Bundler](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/#running-jekyll), which is the most recommended method, specially when hosting on GitHub Pages.

To do that:

1. Open your terminal and type `gem install bundler`
2. Run `bundle update` in order to update all your local gems.
3. Add a `Gemfile` (without any extension) to your site root and inside it type:

   ```
   source 'https://rubygems.org'

   gem 'github-pages'
   gem 'wdm'
   ```
4. Open the terminal and go to your project folder. Run `bundle install`.

This will make bundler install all gem dependencies for you. Adding the [gem `wdm`](https://rubygems.org/gems/wdm/) will allow you to run everything properly on Windows. Bundler will create a file called `Gemfile.lock` where it's gonna be listed all the gems and dependencies used.

**2nd**. Don't leave blank spaces between ```` ``` ```` and the code language:

````
```cs
public interface ITest : ITestKey
{
    Task<string> SayHello(string name);
}
```
````

**3rd**: Add GFM to your `_config.yml` by doing like this:

```
markdown: kramdown
kramdown:
  input: GFM
```

**4th**: Serve Jekyll with bundler by this running this command: `bundle exec jekyll serve --watch`

Done! You should be ok then!

For this part:

> *I have created css style file by running `rougify style monokai >
>   test.css` command*
>
> *I have added that style to served page*
>
> *`<link href="{{ ASSET_PATH }}/css/test.css" rel="stylesheet"
>   type="text/css" media="all">`*

I'm not sure what you're doing, so I'm not on the loop to guide you through.

Hope to have helped!